# Checkout different Repository as per input in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to checkout repository in Azure pipeline which is different then self repo but in same Organization. Here repository name and project name will be passed as input parameter .

I have tried by following example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops but not able to pass with parameter.

I have tried with syntex as below, but not get success.

```
 resources:
   repositories:
   - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository
     type: git
     name: $(project)/$(repo)
     ref: $(branch)
```

Also have tried like

```
- checkout: git://${{ variables.repoName}}@${{ variables.branchRef }}
```

But here getting error at time of running pipeline

```
The String must have at least one character. Parameter name:repositoryName
```

Please help if you have any other way to make it success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Checkout different Repository as per input in Azure Pipeline

According to this thread [Pipeline resource Version property as a variable](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pipeline-resource-version-property-as-a-variable-1/845445):

While we can’t allow variables in that field, this is an excellent use case for [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters).

So, we could not use variable `$(project)/$(repo)` in the resources.

To resolve this issue, we could use the [Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref):

```
parameters:
- name: ProjectName
  displayName: Project Name
  type: string
  default: LeoTest
  values:
  - LeoTest
- name: repoName
  displayName: repo Name
  type: string
  default: TestRepo
  values:
  - TestRepo
- name: branchRef
  displayName: Branch Name
  type: string
  default: Dev
  values:
  - Dev
```

And

```
- checkout: git://${{ parameters.ProjectName}}/${{ parameters.repoName}}@refs/heads/${{ parameters.branchRef}}
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Leo Liu-MSFT for you feedback. Like this its working for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about parameters I'm assuming you are using templates. I was able to achieve the desired result with the following code

```
# File: template.yml
parameters:
- name: project
  type: string
- name: repo
  type: string
- name: branch
  type: string

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: Checkout
  jobs:
  - job: Checkout
    steps:
    - checkout: git://${{ parameters.project }}/${{ parameters.repo }}@${{ parameters.branch }}
```

```
# File: pipeline.yml
extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    project: ProjectName
    repo: RepoName
    branch: BranchName
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidCox88 for your feedback. I have tested and its working for me as well. However other solution suggested by @@Leo Liu-MSFT fit more appropriate for my case.

Comment: No problem at all :) Glad you found a solution that fits your needs